# Hiring manager went silent at start up

Tags: follow-up

I am currently in the running for a software developer position. I had one interview with the person in charge of hiring (not an engineer). I passed the initial call and was given a technical assessment. I finished this on Tuesday and sent over my repo and the deployed app the same day. Since then I have not received any type of reply or update. Is is appropriate to follow up here or should I wait? Whats the best way to follow up without coming off as a pest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've received no notification that the hiring manager has received your assessment, it's reasonable to follow up with a request for confirmation that they received it.

If something got lost in transmission, it could look like *you* have failed to complete your end of the bargain.

A quick email along the lines of:

> Hi,
>
> I just wanted to make sure that you could access the app I sent over on Tuesday.
>
> If you have any problems accessing it, please let me know and I'll get right on it.

etc.

A friendly, helpful tone will avoid the impression of pestfulness. Also, it's a good way to demonstrate that you follow through on your assignments.

Comment: Great answer thanks. This is where it gets a little tricky. I ended up sending it over Monday. It was had some bugs that he pointed out and thought I should fix them before sending it over to engineering. I told him I'd fix them and I did. That's when I sent over my last copy on Tuesday, but he never confirmed getting it or anything. Should I still send another email?

Comment: TBH; I would, tomorrow. I think this tactic still applies